# Is there a PixiOverlay alternative for mapbox?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker, mapbox-ios

I'm developing 3 map-based apps - the first one is a web app (using React.js) and the others are Android and iOS apps (using mapbox).
I'm using Leaflet library with mapbox tiles for the web app, and therefore we enjoy the plugins that Leaflet offers us. One of those plugins is PixiOverlay (https://github.com/manubb/Leaflet.PixiOverlay) which speeds up our map performance.
As a result, I have two questions:

1. Does mapbox as an alternative solution (like PixiOverlay) for their mobile SDK?
2. In PixiOverlay's documentation, they have the following example: https://manubb.github.io/Leaflet.PixiOverlay/french-cities.html. The markers' size is dynamically changed based on zoom level, and they do not override each other. Can I implement something similar by using mapbox SDK?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you handle that? Have you found a solution here?